# Discord.py, send a message to a channel I just created

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I've been trying to run a loop that creates a text channel and directly after that, sends multiple messages to it. I've come up with this code:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    msg = message.content
    guild = message.guild

    if msg.startswith("test") and message.author.id == admin:
        await message.reply("valid", mention_author=True)

        for i in range (10):
            await guild.create_text_channel('test channel')
            for j in range (5):
                await i.send("ah")
```

Unfortunately, it gives me this error:

```
    Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 29, in on_message
    await i.send("ah")
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'send'
```

Could someone help me with this?

Comment: Ask yourself, what is `i`?

Answer (score 1):

You're not using the result of the channel creation, instead you're using `i` which is your index in the iteration. As described in the documentation, [`create_text_channel`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Guild.create_text_channel) returns a `TextChannel` object, try using that instead:

```
for i in range (10):
    channel = await guild.create_text_channel('test channel')
    for j in range (5):
        await channel.send("ah")
```

Answer (score -1):

i, in this case, is an integer, so that is why you can't do:

```
await i.send(<message>)
```

What you are supposed to do is:

```
await channel.send(<message>)
```

Comment: *but what is `channel`? where did you define that?*